Calculating an isosurface of an integral along a line segment in 3d
The motivation behind question is inspired by "metaballs", a fun computer graphics exercise in rendering isosurfaces of a field. In the classic 3D metaballs problem, you have a series of points $\mathbf{r}_n\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and calculate isosurfaces of the field defined by
$$
f(\mathbf{r}) =\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}_n|^2},
$$
which gives you those nice blobs. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs.
My problem extends to finding the field around a collection of line segments in 3D space rather than a collection of points.
In the simple case of a single line segment with end points $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, we could define a field by integrating along the line segment:
$$
f(\mathbf{r}) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - t\mathbf{z}|^2} dt = \int_0^1 (x^2+y^2+z^2-2zt+t^2)^{-1}dt.
$$
This is of the form of a quadratic integral. So we check the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integral), check that the discriminant is always less than or equal to zero ($b^2-4ac = (-2z)^2-4(x^2+y^2+z^2)=-4(x^2+y^2)$), and then apply the forumla it gives us:
$$
f(x,y,z) = \left.\frac{2}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{2ct+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\right)\right|_0^1=...=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^2+z^2-z}\right),
$$
where we made use of the formula $\arctan(A)-\arctan(B)=\arctan\frac{A-B}{1+AB}$ along the way. So seemingly, hooray! we found our solution. However, plotting this on Desmos 3D calculator reveals something very ugly https://www.desmos.com/3d/mqyq1hmzrp:
Here is the plot just typing out the integral into Desmos and letting it numerically integrate before plotting the surface - it gives us exactly what we want (but quite slowly):

Here is the plot when using the above arctan result:

You can see the surfaces are the same on the ends, but there is a section missing in the middle for the arctan version, as well as some rendering artifacts. I've found out that if I add $\pi$ to the value of arctan, I get what appears to be the remaining piece with some rendering artifacts, plus an extra shell around the outside:

Can anyone shed some light on this? I really want a simple closed form for my field $f$. It's not clear to me why this is happening.

The definite integral evaluates to
$$\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \left(\arctan \frac{1-z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \arctan \frac z{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$
but the $\arctan$ terms cannot be joined as you've done to
$$\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \arctan \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^2+z^2-z}$$
because the condition required for doing so is not met - the sum of the individual arctangents does not belong to $\left(-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right)$ for all $x,y,z$ on the surface. The identity does not hold.
To see this for yourself, select the top-down view (XY orientation) and adjust the plot range so that, say, $x\in\left[\dfrac13,\dfrac12\right]$ and $y\in\left[-\dfrac1{10},\dfrac1{10}\right]$. Notice that the red surface $g=C$ does not intersect with the cylinder e.g. $x^2+y^2=\left(\dfrac25\right)^2$, while the purple $h=C$ does. Below is a screenshot of roughly this neighborhood, together with the cylinder in gray:

See also the plot of the sum:


You're a legend! Thanks so much :)
